# ubuntu 12.04 left panel icons missing

Tags: ubuntu, icons, panel

I just notice that the icons in the left panel are all missing. The panel is there, but it is empty. Now I have to use alt + tab to switch between opened applications. I dont know what happened. I am just opening a lot of chrome tabs.
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: I think the correct place to ask it is on: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

you may try this 
`Super`(Windows Key) + `Alt` + `right click` and then select 'add to panel'